# How to append or join multiple times a video file (single file) to make a 10hour long video of that same file using ffmpeg? is there a way?

Tags: ffmpeg

I guess i explain what i need in the title but if not i want to make something like this.

Comment: Havent checked, therefore only as a comment, but have a look here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate and search for this text `This example will loop input.mkv 10 times`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows command line (DOS or `cmd`) using `copy /b 00001.mts+00001.mts K:\Merged.mts` as explained in this step-by-step tutorial, where in your case `00001.mts` is the identical file repeated over and over again:

- https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-free-ways-to-join-spanned-avchd-video-files-into-continuous-clips-on-windows--cms-25830

Connecting the same file 6 times instead of twice, you would just replace in

`00001.mts+00001.mts+00001.mts+00001.mts+00001.mts+00001.mts`